# Angular global function returning the elementId on hover

Tags: angular

I am currently working on an angular project where I need to do a wiki windows. Basically when any element is mouseHovered, its definition is showing inside the wiki window. To do this I wonder if it's possible to have a global function for every htmlElement in the app which will return their id on hover. It would be much more simpler to do it this way instead of calling "ng-mousehover" in each element of template files.

I searched for a while and find nothing which mention such global function so I need your help to know if it's possible and if it is how can I code this.

thank you very much !

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using angular only, or a small vanilla JS code might help you in achieving this will work?

Comment: if I can import the JS script in my angular app it could be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a directive, using as selector any element of html

Imagine you has a service

```
export class MouseService {

  private subject:Subject<any>=new Subject()
  observableID:Observable<any>=this.subject as Observable<any>
  constructor() { }
  message(id:string)
  {
    this.subject.next(id)
  }

}
```

You can has a directive like, see the "selector"

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'a,div,span,input,p',
  exportAs: 'child'
})
export class MouseHoverDirective {
  @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event.target'])
  onHover()
  {
    const id=this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
    if (id)
      this.mouseService.message(id)
  }
  constructor(private el:ElementRef,private mouseService:MouseService){}
}
```

Each time you mouse over a link, span, input, parragraph or div that has an id call to mouseService.message. So if you subscribe in a component you has the "id"

```
this.mouseService.observableID.subscribe(res=>{
   this.result.push(res)
 })
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xun9cr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Updated** the problem is when you has no id in a child element, well, we can change a few the directive

```
@HostListener('mouseover', ['$event.target'])
onHover(target)
{
    const id=this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('id')
    if (id)
      this.mouseService.message(id)
    else
      this.mouseService.message("parent:"+target.parentNode.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

Comment: hi thank you very much it seems to work very well! but unfortunately the hover event do not "include" child element. thus I always get the same div (which is my main panel) while i'm pointing on my elements do you know a way to pass this?

Comment: I'm not prety sure about your question, I update the answer to take account the case child not has id